# Is there a setuptools equivalent to --no-deps?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a dependency that I can install only when some transitive dependencies are excluded (that I don't care about). With pip, you can do --no-deps. If I declare the dependency in my setup.py, however, the system tries to install the transitive dependencies. Is there a way to declare that I only need the library itself, not its dependencies?